# Reload charkick pie_chart without refreshing the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

My goal is once the delete action is submitted the chart should update it's values without refreshing the page here is my code:

in index.html.erb:

```
<div class="chart" style="float: right; width: 500px" >
    <%= javascript_include_tag "//www.google.com/jsapi", "chartkick" %>
      <%= pie_chart current_user.events.group(:app_name).count %>
</div>
```

In destroy.js:

```
   <% if @event.destroyed? %>
   $('#event-' +<%= @event.id %>).slideUp();
   $('.message' ).html('<div class="alert alert-success"><%= escape_javascript(flash.discard(:notice)) %></div>');
   $('.message').toggle(1000);
   $('.chart').html('<%= javascript_include_tag "//www.google.com/jsapi", "chartkick" %><%= pie_chart current_user.events.group(:app_name).count %>');
<% else %>
   $('.message' ).html("<div class='alert alert-danger'><%= flash[:error] %></div>");
<% end %>
```

So I'm trying to reload the chart class but it's not working, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

```
you can use location.reload()/window.location.reload().
```

The Location.reload()method Reloads the resource from the current URL. Its optional unique parameter is a Boolean, which, when it is true, causes the page to always be reloaded from the server. If it is false or not specified, the browser may reload the page from its cache.

```
var intervalID = setInterval(function(){
   $('.chart').each(function(){
      $(this).load(this.href);
   })
}, 900);
```

Comment: Thanks Haresh, but this will refresh the page.. I need it to reload only the (',chart') selector

Comment: try to this ......       var intervalID = setInterval(function(){
    $('.chart').each(function(){
      $(this).load(this.href); })
}, 900);

Comment: It doesn't do anything